# React, access to a specific id (like at css works :nth-child)

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors

I want to add to first and last elements offset (translateX) (left and right, respectively) during hover.

> How to write condition for id in this case?

At css issue was resolved by `:nth-child`

```
class Article extends React.Component{  
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {showIncreaced: null}

    this.getImgStyle = this.getImgStyle.bind(this);
    this.increase = this.increase.bind(this);
    }

    increase (incId) {
        this.setState({showIncreaced: incId})
    }

  getImgStyle (id) {
    return {
      width: '20vw',
      marginRight: '0.5vw',
      marginLeft: '0.5vw',
      position: 'relative',
      zIndex: this.state.showIncreaced === id ? '10' : '0',
      transform: this.state.showIncreaced === id ? 'scale(1.5, 1.5)' : 'scale(1, 1)'
    };
  }

    render(){   
        const TipStyle={                        
                marginBottom: '10px'
        }

    return(                     
        <div style={TipStyle}>                      
          <h2 style={{marginBottom: '1px'}}>{this.props.name}</h2>
          <div>
        {[1,2,3].map((id) => {
            return <img style={this.getImgStyle(id)} src={this.props[`img${id}`]} onMouseOver={this.increase.bind(this, id)} onMouseOut={this.increase} />
        })}                         
          </div>
        </div>                  
); 
}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/5hd3yt4z/

Comment: condition in map, return sth or sth else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even without index you can do it in below way. You only need this () when the param is more than one

Below one is also valid

```
{[1,2,3].map(id => {
        // if (index === 0) { return other }
        // if (index === [1,2,3].length - 1) { return another }
        return <img key={id} style={this.getImgStyle(id)} src={this.props[`img${id}`]} onMouseOver={this.increase.bind(this, id)} onMouseOut={this.increase} />
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.map` function has index as a second argument:

```
    {[1,2,3].map((id, index) => {
        // if (index === 0) { return other }
        // if (index === [1,2,3].length - 1) { return another }
        return <img style={this.getImgStyle(id)} src={this.props[`img${id}`]} onMouseOver={this.increase.bind(this, id)} onMouseOut={this.increase} />
    })}
```

Comment: Also never forget to add a key={id} to img when generating it in loop and key should be unique otherwise only first jsx element will be rendered